# Authenticate templates - AngularJs 2

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular, web, components

We are trying to build our application on Angular2 and we want to authenticate the HTML templates used by Angular.

For ex:

```
  @Component({
       template:'We specify the HTML URL of the template's here' 
   })
```

I want, before angular render the HTML, it should be authenticated on the server side whether the logged in user have the sufficient rights to view that HTML content or not.

I understand there are multiple ways to handle such thing on the client side but I want to authenticate from the server side.